# setTimout undefined function

Tags: javascript, function, nested, settimeout

when I call a function using setTimout like this :

```js
function f2() { console.log("hey"); }
setTimeout("f2()", 3000);
```

It runs perfectly.

But when I wrap everything inside a function f1 like this:

```js
function f1() {
  function f2() { console.log("hey"); }
  setTimeout("f2()", 3000);
}

f1();
```

I get an error message: f2 is not defined.
Why that happens, and how can I get around it?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. Seems like a legitimate issue to me

Answer (score 4):

setTimeout is an async call. It is going to allow the rest of the code to continue on until the delay has been reached. When that happens if the passed value is a string, that string has to be eval'ed, eg `eval("f2()")`. But because the code has already passed, the `f2` function is no longer in a visible scope and therefore cannot be found.

Instead of using a string, just pass the function reference directly

```
setTimeout(f2,3000)
```

demo

```js
function f1(){
  function f2(){ console.log("f2 logging"); }
  
  setTimeout(f2,3000);
}
f1();
```